# JAVA-JAXB/ define class as field

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using jaxb, and as I understood, we define for each element and attribute field, and jaxb reconize this attribute, and put it value into this elemnt. My problem that one of my attribute is class:

```
<div class="hello"> Hi </div>
```

so I want to define in the class div, the next:

```
String class;
public String getClass() {
    return class;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setClass(String class) {
    this.class = class;
}
```

But I can't because - `Syntax error on token "class", invalid VariableDeclarator`

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html#name%28%29) property of [XmlAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) to specify a different name for the mapping variable.

```
String className;
public String getClassName() {
    return clazz;
}

@XmlAttribute(name="class")
public void setClassName(String className) {
    this.className = className;
}
```

It is working perfectly fine

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Div.class);

        Div div = new Div();
        div.setClassName("new-item");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        context.createMarshaller().marshal(div, sw);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());

        String s = "<div class=\"hello\"> Hi </div>";
        Div object = (Div) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(s));
        System.out.println(object.getClassName());

    }

    @XmlType(name = "div")
    @XmlRootElement(name = "div")
    public static class Div {

        private String className;

        @XmlAttribute(name = "class")
        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }

        public void setClassName(String className) {
            this.className = className;
        }
    }
}
```